# Rotating banner similar to App Store's featured banner

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'd like to add a rotating banner similar to the one at the top of the Featured section in the iOS6 version of the App Store. User can scroll infinitely left and right through 4 or 5 different banners. Plus the banners scroll automatically when they're not being interacted with.

I tried to do this using a horizontal scroll view, but when you scroll to the last banner the scroll view stops - it should instead let you keep scrolling, showing the first banner again.

Still trying to figure out the best way to do this - can you do pagination with table view cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it using "cyclic table view" trick. It fakes cycling scrolling by repeating same cells:

1. make `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` return some large value, say, 50000;
2. in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I would do

   ```
   int actualRowNumber = indexPath.row % visibleRowsNumber;
   // fill cell with data for 'actualRowNumber'th object
   ```
3. then in `viewDidLoad` I would scroll this table view to the middle, so that backward scrolling would work right away.

You can make table view horizontal by rotating it 90 degrees counter-clockwise and then rotating each cell 90 degrees clockwise.

Comment: Hmm, that might work... How would you get the four different banners to populate `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` when the number of rows would be so large?

Comment: `%` is modulus operator. `a % b` divides a by b and returns only the remainder. Examples: 6 % 4 = 2, 1276 % 5 = 1. So if you have 4 banners, then banner number for row 0 will be 0, for 1 - 1, for 2 - 2, for 3 - 3, for 4 - 0, for 5 - 1, for 6 - 2, for 7 - 3, for 8 - 0, and so on.

Comment: One issue I see with this - you can't paginate table cells, can you?